# Class with Collection Properties are not binding properly when posted as XML to ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to post my data as `XML` to my asp.net core 3.1 web api. However Collection properties are not getting binded in my model.

Here is my class,

```cs
public class Test
{
    public int Usrno { get; set; }
    public string PCname { get; set; }

    public List<Best> Best { get; set; }
}

public class Best
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }

    public Worst[] Worst { get; set; }
}

public class Worst
{
    public int Ko { get; set; }

    public Win[] Win { get; set; }
}

public class Win
{
    public string Kiss { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `POST` end point,

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Test data)
{
    return Created("", data);
}
```

Here is my `XML` input,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test>
    <Usrno>0</Usrno>
    <PCname>string</PCname>
    <Best>
        <Hello>string</Hello>
        <Worst>
            <Ko>0</Ko>
            <Win>
                <Kiss>string</Kiss>
            </Win>
        </Worst>
    </Best>
</Test>
```

Here is the screen print of the `POST` method in API,

[image]

Here is my `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`,

```cs
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null; })
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

I couldn't figure out what I'm missing. Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `XmlElementAttribute` on `Best` element.

XmlElement attribute indicates that a public field or property represents an XML element when the XmlSerializer serializes or deserializes the object that contains it.

C#

```
public class Test
{
    public int Usrno { get; set; }
    public string PCname { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Best")]
    public List<Best> Best { get; set; }
}
```

The MVC's `XmlSerializerInputFormatter` calls `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the body of the request and the formetter uses this attribute to mark XML elements.

Answer (score 1):

An array or List in xml serialization expects two tags like "Names" and "Name".  You only have one tag so you need to add the attribute XmlElement. This issue occurs in multiple places in your classes.  I fixed all the issue.  See classes below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
            Test test = (Test)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public int Usrno { get; set; }
        public string PCname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Best")]
        public List<Best> Best { get; set; }
    }

    public class Best
    {
        public string Hello { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Worst")]
        public Worst[] Worst { get; set; }
    }

    public class Worst
    {
        public int Ko { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Win")]
        public Win[] Win { get; set; }
    }

    public class Win
    {
        public string Kiss { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support and explanation.